# Add other types to the cache created by tRPC that are not defined in Prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma, react-query, trpc.io

Here is the code that mutates the backend data using Prisma and the frontend cache using tRPC.

```js
  const ctx = api.useContext()

  const createTaskMutation = api.task.create.useMutation({
    onMutate: newTask => {
      ctx.task.getAll.setData(undefined, previousTasks => {
        if (previousTasks === undefined) return [newTask]
        return [...previousTasks, newTask]
      })
    },
    onSuccess: newTask => {
      ctx.task.getAll.setData(undefined, previousTasks => {
        if (previousTasks === undefined) return [newTask]
        return [...previousTasks, newTask]
      })
    },
  })
```

The above code creates a task. You send a title to the backend server and then it processes the data to creates a task. In the onSuccess option, you get the newTask with a Task type, but before processing in the backend that is in the onMutate option, its type is `newTask: { data: Prisma.TaskCreateInput | Prisma.TaskUncheckedCreateInput; }`.

How can I add another type in the state other than the one defined in `schema.prisma` file so that I automatically have a placeholder in the frontend?